# Build won't copy System.Drawing to output folder

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I have an assembly that is deployed to SQL server that references System.Drawing.  Don't ask why, it's a third-party library.  This requires System.Drawing to be in the same directory as the library when I call CREATE ASSEMBLY.  I have added System.Drawing as a 'Content' file to my project, with 'Copy always' to output directory, yet it is never copied.  How can I force VS 2008 to copy this file for me, before I resort to using a build event, which seems unnecessary for such a simple task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know the precise answer, but I wonder if a symbolic link to the assembly in the target directory will suffice? Or possibly the third party could be coerced to look elsewhere with assembly probepaths?

Answer (score 1):

Surely System.Drawing is part of the .NET framework so doesn't need be deployed? Do you have .NET framework installed on the server?